# How can I make a spacing?

Tags: java, swing, layout

We have a program in Java using Eclipse Kepler which I am testing for any errors. I found out that one of the modules in which, Product maintenance has a slight misplacement of the design. The problem that I saw was that the product description (text area which has 3,20 for the scroll pane in-case the description was long) exceeded its space and is now colliding with the product price (another text area who has only 0,20 or "",20). Now I believe that the programmer used a Windows Builder to assist him in his design but never told me how to use it. We have our own copies of the system in case we want something change. But I don't think he taught me how to setup it up and use it. Now I was wondering how I should code this by myself so that I could understand how it should go. Frankly, I am not a Java person but willing to learn. Can you help me? If you need more info, feel free to ask.

```
taProdDesc = new JTextArea(3,20);
spProdDesc = new JScrollPane(taProd, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
tfProdPrice = new JTextField("",20);
```

it looks something like [this](http://gyazo.com/4a8f29a21dbc2cee051832217bfe772a)

I wanted more space in between the two cause I know it should look like a perfect rectangular shape and then a spacing then the next text area/field.

That's what it looks like in the code but I don't think this is the one is where the actual code that I should edit. But for the meantime so me and the programmer can see it, I want to place it there so later on I could tell him where to place it.

Comment: What layout manager is been used?

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean by 'colliding'. Are you able to post a real screen shot? (Or is the one you posted real? It looks like it could be a mock-up.)

Answer (score 0):

depending on the layout manager you are using, you could create space by adding a border,

```
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
```

or by using 'setAutoCreateGaps' and 'setAutoCreateContainerGaps' in GroupLayout:

```
GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel);
layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
```

For more about the LayoutManagers, you should take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
For more about borders: take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)